# Showing User control from another user control's button click in Main Window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created a Wpf application with mvvm architecture.
In main window I have shown a user control. Now I need when I click on a button of the user control then it will hide and open another user control in the same Main window.

Can any one tell me ho to achieve this.

Comment: Please go through this link. It will help you getting good help.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Create an event within the first user control that is raised on button click, for example:

```
public event EventHandler HideButtonClicked;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (HideButtonClicked != null)
        HideButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

In your window, subscribe to that event, and in the event handler you can hide the control (e.g., by settings its `Visibility` to `Collapsed`) and show another one instead (e.g., by setting its `Visibility` to `Visible`):

```
FirstUserControl.HideButtonClicked += OnHideButtonClicked;

private void OnHideButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ((MyUsercontrol)sender).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    SomeOthercontrol.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```